# Estimote BLE beacons not recognized by ios app

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, estimote

I have created an ios app to react to proximity. The app functions as expected when using a transmit beacon function (app screen displays 3 different messages based on proximity to beacon and when within the closest region to the beacon also sounds an audible alarm. When I try to use it with my estimote BLE beacons however, it does not work at all. I have created a microapp program for the estimote cloud based on recommendations from estimote but it still is not functioning at all.